# 8 queens solution is not being outputed

Tags: matlab

I am working on the 8 queens problem in MATLAB and I seem to have trouble returning a solution for the function. When the code is run, MATLAB says "Output argument "solution" (and maybe others) not assigned during call to "C:\Users...". I am kind of confused on how the function returns the solution and why my solution is not assigned even though it is stated within the function. If the output is inside a nested for loop and if statement, is the function not able to access it? Once the function reaches the base case for its recursive steps, how is the solution passed to the previous instances of the functions? Is that also a reason why the output solution is not assigned?

```
function [solution] = PutQueen(column, board)

for row = 1:length(board)
    if can_place(row,column,board) == true % can_place checks if queen is in safe position
        board(row,column) = 1; % place queen on board
        if column==length(board)
          solution = board
        else
          PutQueen(column + 1, board);
        end
        board(row,column) = 0;% remove queen;
    end

end

end
```

Comment: What happens if `can_place` is `false` for all of the `rows` in your board?  Would `solution` be assigned something upon return of the function?

Comment: would it have to be assigned anything since if everything is false, then a solution is not wanted

Comment: Yes, it has to be assigned something.  MATLAB will give you that error because you specified `solution` to be an output to the function.  As such, you need to make sure `solution` is assigned something on exit.

Comment: I can provide a solution, but you need to provide more insight on what `column` and `board` are.  What exactly are these?  What is the data type? `logical`? `double`?

Comment: I see. If I assign solution to something outside the if statement, the solution inside the if statement has the warning value assigned to variable might be unused.

Comment: Yes, because `solution` could possibly get overwritten due to the `if` statement.  If this is something that is part of your design, you can ignore it.

Comment: column is column you want to start from which is usually one and board is the size of the board and it should be an 8 by 8 matrix of zeros. I want to be able to output every solution to the queens problem. Right now the solution inside the if statement is displaying the correct answers but I just cannot get the function to output the answers

Comment: I am afraid recursive formulas can be a hell to debug. You should try the [debugger](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/debugging-code.html?refresh=true). However, is it chess that you work with? May I ask what board representation you have? And where the rules are located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since each solution of your problem is a 2-dimensional matrix and since you want all possible solutions, your final solution must be an array of 2-dimensioanl matrices or simply a 3-dimensional matrix. Where each matrix in 3rd dimension is a solution. You can achieve this by-

```
    function [solution] = PutQueen(column, board)
      solution=[];
      for row = 1:length(board)
         if can_place(row,column,board) == true % can_place checks if queen is in safe position
         board(row,column) = 1; % place queen on board
                if column==length(board)
                  solution = cat(3,solution,board);
                else
                  temp = PutQueen(column + 1, board);
                  if(~isempty(temp))
                  solution = cat(3,solution, temp); %assigning to solution
                  end
                end
                board(row,column) = 0;% remove queen;
         end        
      end    
    end
```

This will give out `solution` which is 3-dimensional array. Now you can obtain each solution by iterating in 3rd dimension.
For eg:- `solution(:,:,1)` will be a solution and so forth.

Comment: If you did this, wouldnt the solution matrix reset to [] every time the function is called again? Im trying what you did above but im getting CAT arguments  dimensions are not consistent

Comment: I've added an empty check in the code to prevent unnecessary concatenation of empty matrix. `solution` matrix wont be reset because its the internal variable of the function. So, assigning `solution = []` in the second call of `PutQueen` will not reset it in the first call.